# What internet browser can I use on pi b+

Tags: web-browsers, web

Can’t use chromium on B+ what can I use ? Firefox doesn’t open either

Comment: You may want to try a text-based browser there are a couple available via apt lynx or w3m.

Comment: Try `dillo` as your web browser.